# Atom inferometer bases on beam spliting - Wavelength vs de Broglie wavelength

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves

I am confused about some principle relations. We look at an atom interferometer which consists of a beam splitter and recombination.

We are given a wavelength $\lambda$ and a paths length difference of $d$. We want to calculate the de Broglie wavelength.

Here is what I am confused about:

1. What's the difference between $\lambda$ and $\lambda_{dB}$ in the first place?
2. Is there a relationship between the phase difference and the momentum?

Here is what I considered:

1. Definition of the de Broglie wavelength, $\lambda_{dB} := \hbar / p$.
2. Calculating the phase difference $\Delta \phi = 2 \pi / \lambda \cdot d$.

I am happy about hints / hints towards lecture notes discussing this. I found one source that mentions

Comment: Ok, the exercise statement was uncomplete. We have to assume a temperature (for instance, super cold atom). Then, we can use the kinetic energy and relate it to momentum to get (together with the atomic mass for the respective atom) the de Broglie wavelength.